# Why does my code always alert "email is badly formatted"

Tags: javascript, firebase

When I run my code there are no errors but it always pops up with an alert saying email is badly format. The email I tried is real fyi. Btw here is the link to the video I watched. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1ULt_No3IY. Also there always seems to be some type of error with the code. If you find anything else please say so!

```js
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "login-signup2.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "login-signup2",
  storageBucket: "login-signup2.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "G-SGE3NJ60DN"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

const auth = firebase.auth()
const database = firebase.database()

const email = document.getElementById('email').value
const name = document.getElementById('name').value
const password = document.getElementById('password').value
const confirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirmPassword').value

const signup = document.getElementById('signup')
const login = document.getElementById('login')

const jumble = /^[^@]+@\w+(\.\w+)+\w$/

signup.addEventListener('click', function() {

  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {
      validateEmail(email)
      validatePassword(password)
      validateConfirmPassword(confirmPassword)
      validateName(name)

      let user = auth.currentUser
      let databaseRef = database.ref()

      let userData = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
        name: name,
        last_login: Date.now()
      }

      databaseRef.child('users/' + user.uid).set(userData)
      alert('User Created')

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Firebase will use this to alert of its errors
      var error_code = error.code
      var error_message = error.message

      alert(error_message)
    })
})

login.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (validate_email(email) == false || validate_password(password) == false) {
    alert('Email or Password is Outta Line!!')
    return
    // Don't continue running the code
  }

  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function() {

      userData = {
        last_login: Date.now()
      }

      // Push to Firebase Database
      databaseRef.child('users/' + user.uid).update(userData)

      // DOne
      alert('User Logged In!!')

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Firebase will use this to alert of its errors
      var error_code = error.code
      var error_message = error.message

      alert(error_message)
    })
})

function validateEmail(email) {
  if (jumble.test(email) == true) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

function validatePassword(password) {
  if (password.length < 6) {
    alert("Email or Password isn't valid")
    return false
  }
}

function validateConfirmPassword(confirmPassword) {
  if (confirmPassword == password) {
    return true
  } else {
    alert("Email or Password isn't valid")
    return false
  }
}

function validateName(name) {
  if (name == null) {
    alert('Name was left open')
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Login + Firebase Database</title>
<div id="containContent" class="font">
  <div id="containForm" class="font">
    <div id="containFormHeader" class="font">
      <h2 id="formHeader" class="font"> Login + Firebase Database </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="containFormContent" class="font">
      <div id="containFormInnerContent" class="font">
        <input type="email" id="name" placeholder="Full Name (Sign Up Only)" class="font">
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="font">
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="New Password" class="font">
        <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password (Sign Up only)" class="font">

        <div id="containButton" class="font">
          <button id="login" class="font">Login</button>
          <button id="signup" class="font">Sign Up</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
                https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the exact message and where does it come from? Your code or FireBase?

Comment: That did not make me any wiser

Comment: There's no message `email is badly formatted` in the code. Do you mean `Email or Password isn't valid`?

Comment: No that is what it said

Comment: I didn't program it to say that either. Must be the error.message

Answer (score 1):

I hate to supply one-line answers but here's the issue

```
<input type="email" id="name" placeholder="Full Name (Sign Up Only)" class="font">
```

That `type` should be "name" not "email"

Comment: Thanks for the fix I also fixed the validate_email function mistake in login addEventLister. It is still showing as "Email is badly formatted"